# how to get scroll mouse event inside the button in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, motionevent

after clicking the button mouse scroll will be activated and scroll up, button value should be increment and when scroll down value decrement. but button outside code working,then button inside code not work.my sample code here.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;
int x,f;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // i need implement code here ,how can i do?                
            return false;
        }
    });
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //if (0 != (event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER)) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
        if (event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_VSCROLL) < 0.0f)
            //selectNext();
        {
            x=Integer.parseInt(button.getText().toString());
            f=x+5;
            button.setText(""+f); 
        }
        else
        {
            x=Integer.parseInt(button.getText().toString());
            f=x-5;
            button.setText(""+f);  
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onGenericMotionEvent(event);
}   }
```

> i need those function inside the touch listener i don't know how can i do,please help me!